# qqplot using plot(model, which=2) shows outlier that falls exactly onto the diagonal line

Tags: r

[image]
The outlier labeled 1 falls exactly on the diagonal line, is it supposed to be like this?

Answer (score 3):

The plot is just identifying the three biggest residuals.  This is governed by the `id.n` argument. The relevant code from `stats:::plot.lm()` is

```r
   if (id.n > 0L) {
        if (is.null(labels.id)) 
            labels.id <- paste(1L:n)
        iid <- 1L:id.n
        ...
        if (any(show[2L:3L])) 
            show.rs <- sort.list(abs(rs), decreasing = TRUE)[iid] 
        ...
   }
```

and then later on when making the plot:

```r
   if (id.n > 0) 
            text.id(qq$x[show.rs], qq$y[show.rs], show.rs)
```

So, the values labeled are not outliers on the quantile scale, but observations with large residuals whether or not they are outliers on the quantile scale.